# How can I improve my 3 decade counter design so that it counts sequentially in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, counter

How can I improve my 3 decade counter design so that it counts sequentially?

I am attempting to build and simulate a 3 decade BCD counter by cascading 3 decades counters that produce an output to indicate when the count of 9 is reached.

My design works, in that it counts sequentially, apart from the times when any of the decade counters reach 9, as this instantenously triggers the next counter to start and instead of going from 008 to 009 or 018 to 019, my design goes from 008 to 019 or 018 to 029, respectively.

Please see extract of code below:

```
  module ThreeDec_Synch_BCDCounter(output [11:0] A, output y, input clk, reset);
  wire DQ1, DQ2;

  Synch_BCD_Counter SBC0({A[3:0]}, DQ1, clk, reset);
  Synch_BCD_Counter SBC1({A[7:4]}, DQ2, DQ1, reset);
  Synch_BCD_Counter SBC2({A[11:8]}, y, DQ2, reset);
endmodule

module Synch_BCD_Counter(output [3:0] A, output y, input clk, reset);
  wire w0, w1, TA1, TA2, TA3;
  wire Q0b, Q1b, Q2b, Q3b;
  supply1  PWR;

  and  #(1) g0 (TA1, A[0], Q3b);
  and  #(1) g1 (TA2, A[0], A[1]);
  and  #(1) g2 (w0, A[0], A[3]);
  and  #(1) g3 (w1, A[0], A[1], A[2]);   
  or   #(1) g4 (TA3, w0, w1);
  and  #(1) g5 (y, A[0], A[3]); 
  
  TFF2  T0 (A[0], Q0b, PWR, clk, reset);
  TFF2  T1 (A[1], Q1b, TA1, clk, reset);
  TFF2  T2 (A[2], Q2b, TA2, clk, reset);
  TFF2  T3 (A[3], Q3b, TA3, clk, reset);  
endmodule
```

Please also see waveform below:

[image]
I have tried about everything that I can think of to try to get it to work, but I am not having much success.

Therefore any asistance/insight that anyone can provide will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your combinational logic is undocumented and it's not at all obvious what you are trying to do. However, you have the simulation, so look at the signals and figure out which signals are not behaving the way you want them to behave. Then, modify the signals so it does behave the way it should. In the meantime, if you have specific questions about how Verilog works please ask them here.

Comment: Hi @Elliot, I am not clear on what you mean by my combinational logic is undocumented and that it is not obvious what I am trying to do. What I am trying to do is to cascade three BCD counters to create a 3 decade counter. Please note that I have spent a considerable amount of time looking at the signals and trying to modify them to aqcuire the desired result, but I am yet to hit that eureka moment; which is why to save myself from losing any more hair, I decided to post the question on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your code is for a learning exercise I will not give a full answer.

`Synch_BCD_Counter` should have 1 more input for enable. This input will replace `PWR`. It also needs to be added to various parts of your combinational logic, which I will leave to you to figure out.

The `y` output will become the enable for other `Synch_BCD_Counter` instances.

All instances should be using the same clock. In general, it is a bad practice to use output logic as a clock of other blocks (there are timing issues and other limitations).

Answer (score 0):

A BCD counter consists of two clocks ClkA,B for two counters , one divide by 2 and the other divide by 5 .You only have one clock in. That was the approach used for TTL then BCD Decoded.

**But for CMOS, they used the shifting 1's approach called  a Johnson counter then BCD Encoded.**

A 2 digit BCD counter also consists of 1 clock for each decade, with a Ripple Carry Out (RCO or CO) to clock the next digit when the 9 transitions to a 0.

When the count = “1001”=9, the decoded output and ClkA  the next stage counts 1 and this stage is reset.

output Q1 = ClkB

Repeat for each of 3 stages and decide if you want the leading Zero's blanked then implement.

### Lessons to learn.

Study existing designs in hardware, learn how the datasheets define specs, then do the same for your logic.  Logic Tables, State Diagrams, Timing limitations, In/Outs etc. Decide if you need to optimize low level code or use libraries with higher level code.

Alternatively study best-in-class microcoder designs from scratch in trade journals , magazines, books, online SuperUser Forums. Avoid Mickey Mouse articles as examples of good design [practice]  ... my mentors were young Prof's in Compilers etc in CSE in the late '70's and ever subroutine had a "HIPO paragraph" in preamble. (IBM term for Heuristic Input Process & Outputs.)

Example of a cascaded counter in hardware.. now replicate in software.

Using [CD4026's](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4026b.pdf?ts=1604584777704&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD4026B) (late 70's vintage CMOS)

[image]

Comment: Humm, I always preach to use a single clock for designs. Why do you think we need two clocks? (I also suspect this is a school assignment. Nobody in real HDL design would use AND, OR or TFF's. You would just write `if (...) A<=0; else A<=A+1;` )

Comment: Hi, I suspect that you are using a different approach to that to which I have based my design on. @Oldfart, it is not actually a school assignment. But, I am self-teaching myself using an academic book. Apart from the concise code, is there any other advantages to using behavioural description for someone who is trying to gain a good grounding in hardware design and synthesis?

Comment: Readability, maintainability etc. if designs get a bit more complex you just want to move on and be efficient. Also debugging is A LOT easier as you are just experiencing yourself. And the approach I am using is what all my colleagues in ASIC/FPGA design use.

Comment: @Oldfart +1 It is because there are actually two counters the last time I looked at an LS90. Unless integrated by another model

Comment: @Oldfart, I couldn't agree with you more, particularly, when it comes to debugging. So, from an expert to a novice, is there much value in gaining a good grounding in hardware design describing the interconnection of gates and flip-flops, as opposed to simply describing the functional beahviour or am I just wasting my time still designing using gate-level description?

Comment: *"is there much value in ..."* No, as along as you understand that there exists a lower layer, I suggest you move on to High Level coding.

Comment: Ok. Understood. Thanks again for your input. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the design of an ancient LS90 is relevant to a question about Verilog design.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  yes but it is essential to understand how any model is created and how to use it. It is not synchronous but async using a ripple carry out to enable the next stage.

Comment: Hi all, can someone please explain to me why this question was deemed not relevant to electronic design and subsequently closed? And is there a way to redress this?

Comment: Aloha, you failed to give a Model of the design specs with signals in/out

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I don't quite understand what you mean by "model of the design spec with signals in/out ". I do not have a design spec per se. I wanted to extend the design of a single decade counter (that I had successfully implemented) to three and that is how I came about with the question initially. Also, I thought that all the relevant info regarding signals in/out were contained within my VHDL code. Please note that I am still trying to familiarise myself with how the site operates and what constitutes a good question.

Comment: A better question defines the design goals ( must haves and nice to haves are different) and then defines what was done, inputs,  outputs, block diagram, relevant signals, layout ,assumptions followed by the missing info in  a question

Comment: @aloHa  this is a rather old question and trivial in CMOS IC's but complicated in firmware.  Study the datasheet .. Block Diagram, Logic Diagram, Timing Signals and interconnection of digits, Then decide your SPECS what you want to do, e.g. leading Zero Blank, (RBI)  and add necessary input/outputs to your logic.

Comment: @oldfart  I updated after OP added comments

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  Ditto as per above

Comment: Hi gents, I appreciate your comments & I will take onboard all that you've said/suggested going forward. But, I have to admit that I'm still confused as to what in particular was wrong with my question, when compared to the other questions that I have asked, which didn't always define all of the things that you've mentioned, but were deemed ok. I feel that given that the question was posted as a result of a problem faced trying to design a digital circuit, it should be relevant to this forum, in particular, as a solution was ultimately arrived at, with contributions from others on this site.

Comment: I don’t have issue with question, someone might have thought too much info or insufficient overview to interpret your logic

Comment: Thank you and let me again reiterate that I very much appreciate your above insights, which I will be referring to going forward. However, with regards to this question, do you think that I would be better off leaving it as closed, seeing as I do not know who closed it?

Answer (score 0):

The working solution that I was aiming for is shown below:

```
module ThreeDec_Synch_BCDCounter(output [11:0] A, output y, input en, clk, reset);
   wire DQ1, DQ2;

   Synch_BCD_Counter SBC0({A[3:0]}, DQ1, en, clk, reset);
   Synch_BCD_Counter SBC1({A[7:4]}, DQ2, DQ1, clk, reset);
   Synch_BCD_Counter SBC2({A[11:8]}, y, DQ2, clk, reset);
endmodule

module Synch_BCD_Counter(output [3:0] A, output y, input en, clk, reset);
    wire w0, w1, TA1, TA2, TA3;
    wire Q0b, Q1b, Q2b, Q3b;

    and  #(1) g0 (TA1, A[0], Q3b, en);
    and  #(1) g1 (TA2, A[0], A[1], en);
    and  #(1) g2 (w0, A[0], A[3], en);
    and  #(1) g3 (w1, A[0], A[1], A[2], en);   
    or   #(1) g4 (TA3, w0, w1);
    and  #(1) g5 (y, A[0], A[3], en); 

    TFF2  T0 (A[0], Q0b, en, clk, reset);
    TFF2  T1 (A[1], Q1b, TA1, clk, reset);
    TFF2  T2 (A[2], Q2b, TA2, clk, reset);
    TFF2  T3 (A[3], Q3b, TA3, clk, reset);  
endmodule
```

And an extract of the waveform is shown below:

[image]

Thanks again to all that contributed!!